# How to load single product a from skuDetails object?

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

As the 'setProductId' in **Google Play Billing Library 2.0.x** has been removed and we must use setSkuDetails for launchingBillingFlow. So how to launch BillingFlow for making a purchase of an item

• I have 3 items which are RadioButtons

• User have to choose one item and Pay by clicking Button

I did the following from docs to fetch price

```
final   List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();

    skuList.add("item1");
    skuList.add("item2");
    skuList.add("item3");
    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);

    mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
            new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                        for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {


                            String sku = skuDetails.getSku();
                            String price = skuDetails.getPrice();
                            if ("item1".equals(sku)) {
                                item1price = price;
                            } else if ("item2".equals(sku)) {
                                item2price = price;


                            } else if ("item3".equals(sku)) {
                                item3price = price;
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
```

How to purchase single product from button click after user selects an chooses an item?

```
mBuyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                    .build();
        }
    });
```

Comment: store clickSkudetail and use that.

Comment: please explain how

Answer (score 1):

try this
initiate

```
private Map<String, SkuDetails> mSkuDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

and add

```
mSkuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);
```

in your code:

```
final   List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();

skuList.add("item1");
skuList.add("item2");
skuList.add("item3");
SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);

mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
        new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                    for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {


                        String sku = skuDetails.getSku();
                        String price = skuDetails.getPrice();

                        mSkuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);

                        if ("item1".equals(sku)) {
                            item1price = price;
                        } else if ("item2".equals(sku)) {
                            item2price = price;


                        } else if ("item3".equals(sku)) {
                            item3price = price;
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

for item1 it will be

```
  mBuyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(mSkuDetailsMap.get("item1")
                .build();
    }
});
```

let me know, if it works.